# Does google syc require google enterprise or will business do

Tags: lightning, enterprise, google, sync

does anyone know if the salesforce Lightning sync for gsuite only works with enterprise license or also with the business types:
I found this link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_sync_admin_google_prep_google.htm&language=en_US&type=0

but m customer sent me an image of his salesforce where it specifically refers to enterprise.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried Lightning Sync with GSuite basic account as well, and it works perfectly fine. In case of enterprise and business edition, there are only very few difference(link below), and those differences are not significant to Lightning Sync requirement.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/6043385

Below is the screenshot of my account which I used to get Lightning Sync working and it was a basic trial account.

[image]

So it would work for Enterprise as well as Business edition.

Comment: If you find it useful, please mark this as selected answer, it will help other members as well.

Comment: thanks ill start checking it out than. have a great day!